# Speeding up a SQL search with multiple tables and joins

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, query-performance

While I am well versed in different areas of the tech universe, I am new to SQL.  I have done a lot of searching, and found many similar questions, unfortunately I have not been able to make much sense of what I have seen, in relating it to my query.  So please be kind...

Our new software at our office allows for the creation of new queries to our database.  I created a search that would prompt for the user to enter a phone number, and the query would search all accounts in our system for that phone number, and display accounts that had that phone number.  There are about 179,000 accounts in our system, and the query is checking for the phone number provided in the prompt in 19 different fields over 7 different tables.

The search works, but takes about 33 seconds, which in today's day and age, feels like way too long, especially to the person who called in, for whose account we are searching for.  But maybe this is as good as it will get?  I do realize I am searching through a lot of info.  I would also be open to limiting the results to accounts in the past 7 years, but when I added this qualifier, it did only show results in the past 7 years, but it did not speed up the search at all, so I took that back out.

Is there any way I can speed up this query?  Our simple phone search that only searches one field is almost instantaneous, and while I don't expect that, I would love to shorten the query time as much as possible.

Here is the code:

```
SELECT
    '[!Enter Phone Number|String|0]' AS 'Phone',
    COLLACCT@.RECNUM AS 'AccountNumber',
    COLLACCT@.COLLECTORNUMBER AS 'Collector',
    COLLDEBT@.LASTNAME || ' ' || COLLDEBT@.FIRSTNAME AS 'MakerName',
    COLLDEBT1@.LASTNAME || ' ' || COLLDEBT1@.FIRSTNAME AS 'Co-MakerName',
    COLLDEBT@.CITY AS 'City',
    COLLDEBT@.STATEANDZIP AS 'StateAndZip',
    COLLACCT@.MASTERACCOUNT AS 'DebtorNumber'
FROM COLLDEBT@
    LEFT JOIN COLLACCT@ ON COLLACCT@.MASTERACCOUNT = COLLDEBT@.RECNUM
    LEFT JOIN U_CELLPHN@ ON U_CELLPHN@.MASTERLINK = COLLDEBT@.RECNUM
    LEFT JOIN COLLDEBT1@ ON COLLDEBT1@.MASTER = COLLDEBT@.RECNUM
    LEFT JOIN U_SPOUSEINFO@ ON U_SPOUSEINFO@.MASTERLINK = COLLDEBT@.RECNUM
    LEFT JOIN U_ASTSCRN@ ON U_ASTSCRN@.MASTERLINK = COLLDEBT@.RECNUM
    LEFT JOIN U_ASTSCRNB@ ON U_ASTSCRNB@.MASTERLINK = COLLDEBT@.RECNUM
    LEFT JOIN AUXDEBTOR@ ON AUXDEBTOR@.DEBTORMASTER = COLLDEBT@.RECNUM
WHERE 
    COLLDEBT@.PHONE = Phone
    OR U_SPOUSEINFO@.SPOUSEPHN = Phone
    OR U_CELLPHN@.CELLMKR = Phone
    OR COLLDEBT1@.PHONE = Phone
    OR U_ASTSCRN@.PHONE0 = Phone
    OR U_ASTSCRN@.PHONE1 = Phone
    OR U_ASTSCRN@.PHONE2 = Phone
    OR U_ASTSCRN@.PHONE3 = Phone
    OR U_ASTSCRN@.PHONE4 = Phone
    OR U_ASTSCRN@.PHONE5 = Phone
    OR U_ASTSCRN@.PHONE6 = Phone
    OR U_ASTSCRN@.PHONE7 = Phone
    OR U_ASTSCRN@.PHONE8 = Phone
    OR U_ASTSCRN@.PHONE9 = Phone
    OR U_ASTSCRNB@.PHONE10 = Phone
    OR U_ASTSCRNB@.PHONE11 = Phone
    OR U_ASTSCRNB@.PHONE12 = Phone
    OR U_ASTSCRNB@.PHONE13 = Phone
    OR U_ASTSCRNB@.PHONE14 = Phone
    OR AUXDEBTOR@.EMPLOYERPHONE = Phone
 GROUP BY 
    MakerName
 ORDER BY 
    MakerName
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If there is other info needed, let me know.  Unfortunately, I can not provide actual account examples due to compliance regulations, but can do my best to assist the assister.  haha

Comment: That's a lot of phones. How's your indexing look for these tables? Any chance you could improve the schema to only store one phone per record in a new and shiny (and indexed) "phone" table?

Comment: If you're only new to SQL, you're not yet "well-versed in tech" haha! What I'd suggest is that you start by searching the tables with the phone numbers, union the customer key, then query the details for each debtor. At the moment with all those left joins, you're potentially multiplying the number of rows to be filtered exponentially.

Comment: @JNevill What, you don't have 15 phones?  psh..

Comment: You have a pretty lousy data structure.  You should consider storing all the phone numbers in a single table, with a single column for the phone number.  Then an index on that table would give you whopping performance.

Comment: OR conditions are always costly. Frequently you will have much faster performance using union all statements instead.

Comment: Are you sure this is MySQL? I don't think it allows `@` in table names without quoting.

Comment: You shouldn't have conditions on tables in `LEFT JOIN` in the `WHERE` clause, those conditions should be in their `ON` clauses.

Comment: Please read this and pay special attention to the section on query performance. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/ Please [edit] your question text to show us, at a minimum, the definintion of the `U_ASTSCRNB` table, and the other tables with `Phone` columns.

Comment: @Barmar is correct. If you mention columns from `LEFT JOIN`ed tables in `WHERE` clauses, you convert those `LEFT JOIN` operations to ordinary inner `JOIN` operations.

Comment: @Steve - I've been doing PC tech and networking for ~25 years, so yeah, I'd say I'm well-versed ;)  Just never needed to work with SQL before...

Comment: To all:  Yes, that is a lot of numbers to search, but they are different numbers, for different people, and unfortunately, I can't change the location of most of the numbers, although I may be able to create a new table to at least consolidate some of them.  

One account may have phone numbers for 10 different people, so if any of those people call in, we would like to search for their number and have that account pop... 

All the phone number fields are indexed.

Comment: @O.Jones, I'll check your link

Comment: Our software is SAAS, and the main table provided by the software maker can't be changed, but table names that start with U_ are tables I created, so I can probably do something about all those...

Comment: @otisbartleh That's the best part about going with a different schema. A `Phone` table where it's just `id | masterlink | phone`. ID can be autogenerated here. You could store 500 phones for one account or 2 phones; the table will shrink and grow in records like it ought to with little to no impact on performance and your code base. You can index on that `phone` field and get steller performance when doing `SELECT masterlink FROM phone WHERE phone = <phonenumber>` (including joins to other tables in there). It would fix a lot of the speed and scaling issues you are running into.

Comment: Honestly, this is turning in to much more than I care to deal with.  I'm not an SQL guy and don't care to be.  I'm also not going to make a new table and then have to transfer hundreds of thousands of phone numbers into it, as well as change multiple aspects of our program to read the new table.  I am just going to forward the link to this thread to our software provider, and let them see all the suggestions here.  Maybe they can do something about it.

Comment: Hi. It seems unlikely that you want the output format that your query returns. In particular if an id has multiple rows in two table, this output returns a row with that id for every possible combination of the values in the two tables. You should already have clearly explained & illustrated desired output for arbitrary input plus what is wrong with what you have in a [mcve] along with code that can be cut & pasted that exhibits your problem. Please do so. Also learn about how left & inner joins work. Also work through a series of smaller queries each with data necessary to the overall result.

Comment: If you just want subrows of tables with a certain value there is no point in *joining*, just query each table and union the results. We join to get rows that are combinations of rows of multiple tables, ie to find rows that can be made that share columns, and you don't actually care about row pairs sharing a value, you just want rows having a value. (There may be a point to *some* joins here.) You need to say exactly what you want returned in terms of the values of your tables. (Forget about your current query.) Ie, again, [mcve]--specification and executable example input & output.

Answer (score 1):

@otisbartleh, just to highlight the basic structure of the approach I describe in my comment. I haven't typed the whole query out, so I've used ellipses to reflect where you'd fill in.

Basically what you're doing is first getting a list of account numbers from all the tables that match the phone criteria, and then, once you have a list of matching (and de-duplicated) account numbers (which I presume ought to be minimal), you're then basically just querying the tables for the details of those accounts (which ought to be quick).

If you're running this query several times a day to find different phone numbers, you might want to create a table that indexes all the phone numbers in the database and matches them to account numbers (which might take a little bit of time initially), and then it's easy to look up the account(s) that match any particular individual phone number, because you already have the table with the cross-reference prepared.

```
WITH u_astscrn_matches AS
(
    SELECT  
        masterlink AS master_debtor_id
    FROM 
        U_ASTSCRN@
    WHERE   
        @phone IN (phone0, phone1, phone2, ...)
)
,u_astscrn_b_matches AS
(
    SELECT  
        masterlink AS master_debtor_id
    FROM 
        U_ASTSCRNB@
    WHERE   
        @phone IN (phone10, phone11, phone12, ...)
)   
...

,all_matches AS
(
    SELECT master_debtor_id FROM u_astscrn_matches
    UNION
    SELECT master_debtor_id FROM u_astscrn_b_matches
    UNION
    ...
)

SELECT
    ...

FROM
    all_matches AS am

LEFT JOIN
    COLLDEBT@ AS cd
    ON (cd.recnum = am.master_debtor_id)

LEFT JOIN
    ... --join onto other tables to get all the debtor details
```

Comment: I will try these suggestions and report back.  I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

"Don't splay an array across columns."

Restructure the schema.  Have a table primarily for phone numbers.  It could probably have a 1:many link from persons to phones.  (Or you might need many:many.)

With that, it is a simple `JOIN` and a single test for the phone number.

And it gets rid of all 15 columns for phone numbers.  And it deals more gracefully with people with fewer than 15 phones.  And it lets a person have more than 15.

Answer (score 0):

The most straight forward solution is to use UNION, like this:

*(Note: The query is actually less complicated than it looks; I left in the original pieces each UNION piece replaces for clarity.)*

```
SELECT
    '[!Enter Phone Number|String|0]' AS 'Phone',
    COLLACCT@.RECNUM AS 'AccountNumber',
    COLLACCT@.COLLECTORNUMBER AS 'Collector',
    COLLDEBT@.LASTNAME || ' ' || COLLDEBT@.FIRSTNAME AS 'MakerName',
    COLLDEBT1@.LASTNAME || ' ' || COLLDEBT1@.FIRSTNAME AS 'Co-MakerName',
    COLLDEBT@.CITY AS 'City',
    COLLDEBT@.STATEANDZIP AS 'StateAndZip',
    COLLACCT@.MASTERACCOUNT AS 'DebtorNumber'
FROM COLLDEBT@
    LEFT JOIN COLLACCT@ ON COLLACCT@.MASTERACCOUNT = COLLDEBT@.RECNUM
WHERE 
    COLLDEBT@.PHONE = Phone
    OR COLLDEBT@.RECNUM IN (        
        -- LEFT JOIN U_CELLPHN@ ON U_CELLPHN@.MASTERLINK = COLLDEBT@.RECNUM
        SELECT MASTERLINK FROM U_CELLPHN@  WHERE CELLMKR = Phone
        -- OR U_CELLPHN@.CELLMKR = Phone        
        UNION       
        -- LEFT JOIN COLLDEBT1@ ON COLLDEBT1@.MASTER = COLLDEBT@.RECNUM
        SELECT MASTER FROM COLLDEBT1@ WHERE PHONE = Phone
        -- OR COLLDEBT1@.PHONE = Phone
        UNION
        -- LEFT JOIN U_SPOUSEINFO@ ON U_SPOUSEINFO@.MASTERLINK = COLLDEBT@.RECNUM
        SELECT MASTERLINK FROM U_SPOUSEINFO@ WHERE SPOUSEPHN = Phone
        -- OR U_SPOUSEINFO@.SPOUSEPHN = Phone
        UNION
        -- LEFT JOIN U_ASTSCRN@ ON U_ASTSCRN@.MASTERLINK = COLLDEBT@.RECNUM
        SELECT MASTERLINK
        FROM U_ASTSCRN@ 
        WHERE PHONE0 = Phone
            OR PHONE1 = Phone
            OR PHONE2 = Phone
            OR PHONE3 = Phone
            OR PHONE4 = Phone
            OR PHONE5 = Phone
            OR PHONE6 = Phone
            OR PHONE7 = Phone
            OR PHONE8 = Phone
            OR PHONE9 = Phone
        -- OR U_ASTSCRN@.PHONE0 = Phone
        -- OR U_ASTSCRN@.PHONE1 = Phone
        -- OR U_ASTSCRN@.PHONE2 = Phone
        -- OR U_ASTSCRN@.PHONE3 = Phone
        -- OR U_ASTSCRN@.PHONE4 = Phone
        -- OR U_ASTSCRN@.PHONE5 = Phone
        -- OR U_ASTSCRN@.PHONE6 = Phone
        -- OR U_ASTSCRN@.PHONE7 = Phone
        -- OR U_ASTSCRN@.PHONE8 = Phone
        -- OR U_ASTSCRN@.PHONE9 = Phone
        UNION
        -- LEFT JOIN U_ASTSCRNB@ ON U_ASTSCRNB@.MASTERLINK = COLLDEBT@.RECNUM
        SELECT MASTERLINK
        FROM U_ASTSCRNB@ 
        WHERE PHONE10 = Phone
            OR PHONE11 = Phone
            OR PHONE12 = Phone
            OR PHONE13 = Phone
            OR PHONE14 = Phone
        -- OR U_ASTSCRNB@.PHONE10 = Phone
        -- OR U_ASTSCRNB@.PHONE11 = Phone
        -- OR U_ASTSCRNB@.PHONE12 = Phone
        -- OR U_ASTSCRNB@.PHONE13 = Phone
        -- OR U_ASTSCRNB@.PHONE14 = Phone
        UNION       
        -- LEFT JOIN AUXDEBTOR@ ON AUXDEBTOR@.DEBTORMASTER = COLLDEBT@.RECNUM
        SELECT DEBTORMASTER FROM AUXDEBTOR@ WHERE EMPLOYERPHONE = Phone
        -- OR AUXDEBTOR@.EMPLOYERPHONE = Phone
    )    
 GROUP BY 
    MakerName
 ORDER BY 
    MakerName
```

Also, some speed may be gained by changing the OR sub-queries to IN lists; more recent versions of MySQL have done some optimizations on those.